# Why JSON updates are not showing in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, ajax

I have a JSON file. It runs successfully for the first time. But when I update something in my json file, that update is not showing in my webpage. Only the old data is showing. I tried to refresh page several times, but its not working.
I am using xampp local server for and ajax for my code to call json data.

Please help.

My JSON file

```
[
 {
  "name": "Aseem",
  "age":29,
  "salary":50000
 },
 {
  "name": "John",
  "age":23,
  "salary":53000
 },
 {
  "name": "Erica",
  "age":25,
  "salary":52000
 }
]
```

Comment: how do you load the file?

Comment: Set the cache headers in your server for this file to never cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often of the contents of something isn't refreshing, it is likely as a result of the cache. Web browsers cache content that is loaded over the network, to reduce future loading times and data required to load those resources.

You can test this yourself, by opening the Developer Tools in your browser (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I` in Google Chrome), go to the Network tab (or similar) and look for a tick box that says 'Disable cache'. Now if you refresh the page you should be able to see the updated version.

If you wanted to fix this programmatically, an easy way is to add a query to the end of the URL. Since this is technically a new URL, the browser will re-request the resource, but the query will be ignored by the webserver, so there's no side effect. An example of this can be seen below:

```js
let noCache = Date.now().toString(16);
url = `${url}?noCache=${noCache}`;

// Make request with URL
```

Comment: I did this, but the json still won't load on my webapp. I have it on the server and everything.... I had another server that loaded it, but only after a day or so...

Answer (score 1):

check 2 points

1, ajax data is new?
2. clear your broswer cache and try it again.